# ¿Como activar el bombillo de ayudas en Android Studio?

Tags: android

amigos como puedo activar el bombillo de ayudas en Android Studio, ya que tengo que implementar manualmente o no puedo ver donde tengo errores de código hasta el momento de ejecución... la verdad eso es mucho proceso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código de presencia sea texto

Comment: Bienvenido @Polintec, no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio. Lee también [ask] que te proporciona información para realizar preguntas y obtener buenas respuestas. Agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas en la esquina inferior derecha, tienes un icono que esta desactivado, este es el "inspector":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para activar la ayuda, debes dar clic sobre el icono y deshabilita "Power Save Mode"**, además configura el nivel de resaltado a "Inspections" :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]